# How do i instantiate a UIMap in Class file that i have created

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I"m trying to instantiate a UIMAp (the reason i need this is currenly i'm having an error thats occuring and i think its because i need to instantiate it). I've read online about how to do it but my UI maps are named the same as my cs files that are created.  and i cant seem to see if i'm actually instantiating it correctly since its just a class. I have reference in the file 
which is

`using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common.UIMap;`

But i dont think i'm accessing it or am i and just dont know 
I tried this code `HomePage MyNewUIMap = new HomePage();`

but i don't believe its correct here is my folder structure

For example my folder and file structure is

--> Home (folder) 
---->HomePage.uiTest(UIfile) 
------->HomePage.cs (file)
----------->HomePage.Designer.cs (file)

Answer (score 3):

I normally keep a utility class that does nothing but instantiate my maps.  Then, I can just call `MyUtility.HomePage.objectOnHomePage` when I need to interact with that object, and I don't need to instantiate each map on each test class.  However, the actual method for instantiating my maps is done below:

```
public HomePage myHomePageMap
{
    get
    {
        if (_homePage == null)
            _homePage = new HomePage();
        return _homePage;
    }
}
private HomePage _homePage;
```

I do it this way to make sure that, if I've already instantiated the map, I don't create a duplicate instance of it.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for responding.  I'm still not able to access any of the methods of the UI map so i don't think i'm instantiating the correct object.  When i instantiate it on the MSDN it states i'm suppose to see all these methods such as AddUIobjects and clear and Contain etc... [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitest.common.uimap.uimap.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: The problem is because there both partial classes and file names are the same.  Its only allowing me to access the partial class that have my methods and properties the partial class with the same name that is the UImap partial class,  i'm not able to access i don't know why?.

Comment: The `Remarks` section of the page you linked to answers your question.  You shouldn't be using the methods of the class itself in your tests, only the methods that the test builder adds to the map.designer.cs file or the ones you add manually to the map.cs file.  For example, the .AddUIObjects() method would be used by the TestBuilder to build your map, but if you added a method `ClickOnThisObject()` to your partial class, you can do `MyUtility.HomePage.ClickOnThisObject();`.  Also, if trying to access objects and methods from the .designer.cs file, you simply navigate by the class structure.

Comment: Still, Intellisense should be able to help you along the way, and knowing the tree structure of the map helps as well.

Comment: Hi ryan i'm sorry but i didnt quite get it.  Currently what is happening is that   as i'm going between my classes and test method i think the object that i'm trying to access is getting dispose or unavailable even though my screen has not refreshed or anything.  the actual message is this "UITestControlNotAvailableException" The exception that is thrown when the UI test framework attempts to access a UI element that is no longer available or cannot be accessed. I thought instantiating the UI Map again would be solving this but i'm somewhat confused either on using this property to instantiat

Comment: it or the best way on doing this or if instantiating it would solve the issue.  I went ahead in created the static class Myutility with some method on it but i'm not sure if i need to call one of the Method to instantiate this.

Comment: It looks like this has nothing to do with the UIMap, if the Control is not available the framework might not be able to find it or it's not visible on screen (but through scrolling for example).

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and upvote the answer because it answers your question even through your problem is not related to your question